React RichText not showing in html format?
I've used React Quill for RichText Editor. And also saved data as html format. The Response shows in the Api like below:
"education": "<ul><li>Bachelor of Science (BSc) in Computer Science &amp; Engineering, </li><li>Master of Science (MSc) in Computer Science &amp; Engineering</li></ul><p><br></p>"

I used the following code to show in html format to view the data. But the data is showing without the list format. Only show text data.
import DOMPurify from "dompurify"; // Import DOMPurify at the beginning of your file

// Function to sanitize HTML to prevent XSS attacks
const sanitizeHTML = (html) => {
  return {
    __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html),
  };
};

// JSX for rendering education with proper formatting
<div
  className="text-lg"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={sanitizeHTML(jobDescription.education)} // Sanitize and render HTML
/>

Expected Result:

Bachelor of Science (BSc) in Computer Science & Engineering,
Master of Science (MSc) in Computer Science & Engineering


maybe you are using some sort of CSS Reset?

i think its because of tailwind css add list-disc class to ul or you can also use prose class of tailwindcss to div to add typographic defaults.
Otherwise i checked it its working perfectly. your code is correct
